# Want to see hierarchical view of contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 32-bit, Windows10 Enterprise 64-bit.

Behind the interface, MS Outlook Contacts folders seem to be stored in a hiarchy.  Right-click a parent folder of contacts, choose 'Move Folder', and various contact folders are displayed in a nested way.

However all contact folders in the navigation pane are displayed in a flat representation.

I have many many contacts organized in subfolders.  How do I display the nested organizational structure in the contacts navigation pane?

Comment: You can use a folder view to see your contacts in nested organizational structure via pressing Ctrl + 6 in Outlook client.

Comment: @Aidan, I believe you need to move your comment to answer.

Comment: @Aidan, since you've not moved your comment to an answer, I shall.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a folder view to see your contacts in nested organizational structure by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> in the Outlook client.

*as [Want to see hierarchical view of contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/1524361/want-to-see-hierarchical-view-of-contacts#comment2310103_1524361) explains, paraphrased.*